# How to get jQuery chat to respond to me

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I am trying to build a front end chat feature on my mobile app. I have been following a youtube series on how to do it, but at video 14 the gentleman went in a different direction than I wanted. I want to be the first person to type, and then have the "bot" respond to me (in a predetermined string). Unfortunately how he has it , is that the bot asks your name, then you respond, and then the bot says nice to meet you (name)

My question is using the code I'll provide, how can I get the "bot" to respond to me after I type first?

```
$(function(){

  $("#chatSend").click(function(){

    var username = "<span class = 'chatUsername' =>CNN_News: </span>";

    var newMessage = $("#chatTextBox").val();

    $("#chatTextBox").val("");

    var prevState = $("#chatContainer").html();

    if (prevState.length > 7){
        prevState = prevState + "<br>";
    }

    $("#chatContainer").html(prevState + username + newMessage);

    $("#chatContainer").scrollTop($("#chatContainer").prop("scrollHeight"));

  });

});
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on *exactly* what you want. Could you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, just set up a JSFiddle account. Heres the link https://jsfiddle.net/mattmega4/91svxht9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is, that bot asks his question first, then you type your question/answer...etc, and you want to be the first, then just ignore what the bot sends.

When you load the page, and chat starts, clear whatever was in the chat window.
    //first- start by emptying whatever bot entered
    $("#chatContainer").empty();

```
//start your first line
```

or ... if you want a better answer, then explain how the bot works.

The question remains confusing, but here is a quick bot demo thats very basic and simple.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/91svxht9/4/
```

And code

Javascript

```
var username = "John";
var botname = "Bot";
var sendBtn = $("#chatSend");
var chatContainer = $("#chatContainer");
var botResponses = [
    "Wow, thats cool", "Im a bot", "who are you", "thats soo cool" , "give me all your money"
];
var addMessage = function(who, msg) {
    var ownerclass = "bot";
    if ( who == username ) {ownerclass = "mine";}
    chatContainer.append("<div class='message "+ownerclass+"'><span>"+who+"</span>: "+msg+"</div>");
    sendBtn.attr("disabled", true);//disable send until bot responds
    chatContainer.scrollTop($("#chatContainer").prop("scrollHeight"));    
}
var botRespond = function() {
    var msg;
    msg = botResponses.shift();
    if ( !msg ) { msg = "i have nothing more to say";}
    addMessage(botname, msg);
    sendBtn.removeAttr("disabled");//disable send until bot responds
}


$(function(){
  sendBtn.click(function() {
    var msg = $("#chatTextBox").val();
    if ( !msg ) {alert("enter message before clicking send");return false;}
    addMessage(username, msg);
    setTimeout(function() {botRespond();}, 2000);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="chatContainer">

</div>

<div id="chatControls">
  <textarea id="chatTextBox" placeholder = "Enter your message       
  here...">
  </textarea>
  <button id="chatSend">Send</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#chatContainer{
    width: 95%;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: .9;
    overflow-y:scroll !important;
    padding: 5px;
}
#chatTextBox{
    resize: none;
    width: 65%;
    height: 35px !important;
    float: left;
    opacity: .9;
}
#chatControls{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#chatSend{
    resize: none !important;
    width: 50%;
    height: 35px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 30%;
    float: right;
    opacity: .9;
    padding: 5px;
}


.message > span {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.chatBot{
    color: #484d97;
    font-weight:  bold;
}
.message {margin-top: 4px;}
.message.mine {
   color: black;   
}
.message.bot {
   color: gray;   
}
.message.bot>span {
   color: green;   
}
```

Comment: Here is my JS FIddle,  jsfiddle.net/mattmega4/91svxht9      The bot works by initially typing "What is your name" and then you respond "bob" then it says "hello bob, how are you"       what I want to do is be able to type first and then have the bot says exactly, "Ok, how is this?"